# What is the position of Lord Shiva as per Srimad-Bhagavatam

Tags: shiva, bhagavata-purana

I read somewhere that Lord Shiva is regarded as a devotee of Sri Krishna as per Srimad-Bhagavatam. The name of Shiva or Rudra is mentioned as the name of the Para-Brahman in many parts of the Vedas.

**What is the position of Lord Shiva as per Srimad-Bhagavatam--is He just a Jiva or Deva or another form of Bhagavan? Please cite proper references.**

Comment: I think there's difference between Rudra and Shiva. Rudra is among Trimurti and Shiva is Parabrahman.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, Lord Shiva is a form of the Para-Brahman or the Supreme Godhead as per Srimad-Bhagavatam**. This becomes clear from the 12th chapter of the 11th Canto, where Markandeya gets darshan of Shiva and Parvati:

> Once travelling in tge sky with Rudrani and the ganas on His bull, **Bhagavan Shiva** saw Markandeya practising austerity (Sloka 3).
>
> **Sri Bhagavan [Shiva]** said: Markandeya has attained supreme devotion to Bhagavan, Who is Changeless, and so this Brahmarshi does not want any other boon. (sloka 6)
>
> Saying this, Sri Bhagavan [Shiva] who is the destination of all honest ones and Ishwara of every Vidya and of everybody entered into Markeendyea's hriday-aakaasha with the help of yogamaya (sloka 8-9).

**So its clear that Lord Shiva has been demonstrated as Sri Bhagavan Who uses His Yogamaya**.

**Bhagavan can never be two.This is also clear from the same Canto:**

> Bhagavan is He Who has All the six qualities (Bhaga etc) as the leelakamala of His hand, and Dharma as his fan (chamara) and yasha as its breeze(chapter 11,sloka 18).

The definition of 'Vaishnava' is also provided beautifully in the same canto:

> **That parama pada is Vaishnava, which has to be obtained by the yogis by 'neti neti'vichara in one's own cave in the heart** (chapter 6, sloka 32).

So its clear that Srimad-Bhagavatam accepts Lord Shiva as one form of the Supreme Godhead and also accepts the (neti neti) vichara-marga as one way of attaining Him.

**So besides projecting Sri Bhagavan as Sri Vishnu (and Sri Krishna) and glorifying the path of bhakti or devotion in the most beautiful way, this great scripture accepts Shiva as just another form of Supreme God and also accepts jnanamarga wholeheartedly.**

Answer (score 7):

The Srimad Bhagavatam indeed portrays Lord Shiva as the greatest of all Vaishnnavas:

> *nimna-gānāṁ yathā gaṅgā*
>
> *devānām acyuto yathā*
>
> ***vaiṣṇavānāṁ yathā śambhuḥ***
>
> *purāṇānām idam tathā*
>
> **English Translation**: Just as the Ganga is the greatest of all rivers, Lord Acyuta the supreme among deities and **Lord Sambhu the greatest of Vaishnavas**, so Srimad-Bhagavatam is the greatest of all Puranas. (**Srimad-Bhagavatam 12.13.16**)

At the same time, the Srimad Bhagavatam also portrays Lord Shiva as the Supreme Brahman:

> *śrī-prajāpataya ūcuḥ*
>
> ***deva-deva mahā-deva***
>
> ***bhūtātman bhūta-bhāvana***
>
> *trāhi naḥ śaraṇāpannāṁs*
>
> *trailokya-dahanād viṣāt*
>
> **English Translation**: The prajāpatis said: **O greatest of all Devas, Mahādeva, Supersoul of all living entities and cause of their happiness and prosperity**, we have come to the shelter of your lotus feet. Now please save us from this fiery poison, which is spreading all over the three worlds. (**Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.21**)
>
> *tvam ekaḥ **sarva-jagata***
>
> ***īśvaro bandha-mokṣayoḥ***
>
> ***taṁ** tvām arcanti kuśalāḥ*
>
> *prapannārti-haraṁ gurum*
>
> **English Translation**: O Lord, you are **the cause of bondage and liberation of the entire universe** because you are **its ruler**. Those who are advanced in spiritual consciousness **surrender** unto you, and therefore you are the cause of mitigating their distresses, and you are also the **cause of their liberation.** We therefore worship Your Lordship. (**Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.22**)
>
> *guṇa-mayyā sva-śaktyāsya*
>
> ***sarga-sthity-apyayān** vibho*
>
> *dhatse yadā sva-dṛg bhūman*
>
> ***brahma-viṣṇu-śivābhidhām***
>
> **English Translation**: O Lord, you are **self-effulgent and supreme**. You create this material world by your personal energy, and you **assume the names Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Maheśvara when you act in creation, maintenance and annihilation.** (**Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.23**)

So basically according to Srimad Bhagavatam, Lord Shiva is the Supreme Brahman as well as the greatest of all Vaishnavas.

Comment: There is only one Brahman. Brahman can't be a devotee.

Comment: In Ramayana lord rama is vaishnava

Answer (score 0):

Hare krishna!
Your humble servant, joy das.

What respected surya kanta ji said is a false assumption due to less analysis

In Purport Of SB 8.7.21 (http://vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/21) , Prabhupada explains “Whenever prayers for protection are offered to Lord Śiva, actually Lord Viṣṇu is indicated ”

Are there any evidences from shastra’s which hold it true ?

There are many more contradiction’s that are in subsiquent verses , In SB 8.7.23 (http://vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/23)

” O lord, you are self-effulgent and supreme. You create this material world by your personal energy, and you assume the names Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Maheśvara when you act in creation, maintenance and annihilation.”

How can lord siva create himself ? And how can he create material world ?

Again in SB 8.7.24 (http://vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/24) , Prabhupada says , ” When Lord Śiva is worshiped as Parabrahman, the worship is meant for Lord Viṣṇu .”

Sometimes even great devotees like Narada and Sukadeva Goswami are addressed as “bhagavan”, as being all-knowing and as being like the Supersoul (Ref. SB 1.2.2, 1.5.6-7 etc), but with the clear understanding that they are so empowered by virtue of their pure devotion to the Supreme Lord. Similarly, Yamaraja is described as being present as the witness in everyone’s heart – but by the empowerment of Paramatma, not independently. (Ref. SB 6.1.48)

The prayers offered by the prajapatis to Lord Shiva are offered in the spirit of acknowledging his position as a guna-avatara, an empowered representative of the Supreme Lord, and not to Lord Shiva as an independent entity separate from Lord Vishnu nor as sarva-karana-karanam. Thus these glorifications are indirectly glorification of the supreme Lord or Paramatma, as much as the reception offered to the ambassador of a country is actually indirectly offered to the head of State.

This is explained in the purports to these texts “Lord Brahma and Lord Shiva are incarnations of Lord Vishnu and are known as shaktyavesa-avataras. They are endowed with a special power like that of Lord Vishnu, who is actually all-pervading in their activities. Therefore whenever prayers for protection are offered to Lord Shiva, actually Lord Vishnu is indicated, for otherwise Lord Shiva is meant for destruction. Lord Shiva is one of the ishvaras, or the controllers known as shaktyavesa-avataras. Therefore he can be addressed as having the qualities of Lord Vishnu. Lord Vishnu acts through Lord Shiva in the creation of the material world. Lord Shiva acts on behalf of Lord Vishnu.”

(SB 8.7.21)as described in Brahma Samhita, the material creation is known as Devi dhama where Durgadevi reigns supreme, but above that is Mahesh Dham under the jurisdiction of Lord Shiva wherein he is supreme, and even above that is Hari dhama – Lord Brahma worships the Primeval Lord Govinda “who has allotted their respective authorities to the rulers of those graded realms.” (Brahma Samhita 5.43)

Finally, everything is placed in proper perspective when we study what Lord Siva’s own response was to these prayers --- Lord Shiva accepts the prayers with a clear understanding of who the Supreme Personality of Godhead is, as well as his own position in relation to the Lord. He accepts these prayers on behalf of the Supreme Lord Hari, just as a tax-collector accepts taxes not on his own account but on behalf of the government.